# How to display firebase firestore data inside widgets?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Please help with Firebase.
I kindly ask you to read to the end!

This question has been tormenting me for about a week, all week, I can't find an answer and continue developing my application. The official documentation does not give, and the guides do not give an answer.

I'll start with what I want to implement in my application.
My application is a reference book consisting of articles. Articles contain titles and their contents.
The name and their contents are in my firebase. These are the ones I need to read, insert into widgets already marked up for this. I could do it manually, but a lot of articles are easier to read from firestore or realtime database.

For clarity, so that you can better understand my plan, I ask you to familiarize yourself with the picture. Everything is written and clearly shown on it.

**[A picture of my plan. Please take a look](https://ibb.co/7W1kdwx)**

I will say that I have tried anything, 24/7 all week, I am trying to implement it, but nothing works out for me.
One good person told me that I need to parse JSON into a flutter and use a JSON call, but he didn't really explain how to do it.

If I understand something in DART and can figure it out, then firebase is a difficult test for me, which does not lend itself at all to teaching. Please help me - you are the only hope.

Also, please kindly write where and what to insert, or write a code snippet, it will help not only me, but also many others. Do good and it will come back!

My bad code at the moment, which I need to change, as shown in the screenshot:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:operbooktest/HomeTest.dart';
import 'package:operbooktest/Pages/BookTest/Chapter_One/Article1.dart';
import 'package:operbooktest/settings_pages.dart';

class Checking extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = "Checking";
  @override
  State<Checking> createState() => _CheckingState();
}

class _CheckingState extends State<Checking> {
  Future<QuerySnapshot> getthosedocuments() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('testt')
        //.limit(1)
        .get();
    return snapshot;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          future: getthosedocuments(),
          builder: (context, snapshotsub) {
            if (snapshotsub.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }

            final docs = snapshotsub.data!.docs;

            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: snapshotsub.data?.size,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final doc = docs.elementAt(index);
                return Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        const Row(
                          children: [
                            Flexible(
                              child: Text(
                                'TitleText',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 24,
                                  fontFamily: 'TimesNewRoman',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  letterSpacing: 1,
                                  height: 1.5,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        const Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            Flexible(
                              child: Text(
                                'TextRight',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontFamily: 'TimesNewRoman',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  letterSpacing: 1,
                                  height: 1.5,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                        ),
                        const Row(
                          children: [
                            Flexible(
                              child: Text(
                                'Text',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontFamily: 'TimesNewRoman',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  letterSpacing: 1,
                                  height: 1.3,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Text((doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['DescriptionArticleTest'] as String? ??""),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The most important thing is that the text from firebase is not displayed in the list.
Example:

```
return Center(
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: const [
                            Flexible(
                              child: Text( -E-X-A-M-P-L-EHow to display firebase firestore data inside widgets--->TITLE ARTICLE <-E-X-A-M-P-L-E----
```

***On top should be the title of my article after Flexible in any text widget. The code is just for an example that you need to display data from firebase not in a list, but inside widgets.***

Answer (score 0):

```
final doc = docs.elementAt(index);
```

therefore, to access the `doc`, use the key that you used to set data in firebase:

```
  {
    'title': 'hello',
    'description': 'description here'
  }
```

and use them like this

```
Text(doc['title']) //for title
Text(doc['description']) //for description
```

and remove `const` from Row before doing this

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In your code snippet, where "(index)" should there be something else under index, or should it be left like this?

Comment: index is from Listview.builder leave it as it is.